# Finding CDF of a function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cdf

I am simulating a research paper for my semester project where I need to implement few algorithms on (preferably) Matlab. 
I need to calculate an integration of function which is product of cdf of a normal distribution and another function as in eq [25] : [To simulate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7WHA.png)

I have written the code of most part but while writing function for 'normcdf' I am getting an error 'Non scalar arguments must match in size' which is apparently because arguments must be of type Single or Double but I am passing a function. I don't get how can a function be passed as single or double.

```
    P = 20; D0 = 50; sig = -104; beta = -15; lamF = 320e4; 
    lamD = 5e4; lamA = 1/1800; T = 10000; 
    nbar = pi*power(D0,2)*lamD*(1-exp(-2*0.001* lamA));
    muI_func = @(d2) 2*P*nbar*(power(d2,2)*(-2.5*power(d2,-3.5)) - 2*(d2*8.75*power(d2,-4.5) + 39.375*power(d2,-5.5)))/power(D0,2);
    muI = muI_func(D0) - muI_func(1); %d2 min = 1;
    fun = @(d2) 2*power(P/D0,2)*power(d2,-3);
    temp = integral(fun, 1, D0);            %d2min = 1;
    delI = temp - power(muI/nbar,2);
    delI = delI*sqrt(nbar);

    % Errors seem to begin here
    xi = @(d1) ((P*power(d1,-2.5) - sig*beta)/beta - muI)/delI;                 
    phi = normcdf(xi,0,1);
    fun2 = @(d1) 2*pi*lamF*d1*phi(d1)*exp(-lamF*pi*power(d1,2));
    out = integral(fun2,1,D0);
```

At end I want value for out, which I will plot later against lamD, where lamD was used in calculating muI and delI. The only variable here is d1 and workspace shows constants values calculated for muI and delI while P, beta and sig were constants to begin with.

Also, if you feel that while integrating I will get more errors, please tell so. This  is my first program on Matlab which I am doing by myself.

Comment: Here is full code and paper from where I am simulating: [link](https://github.com/Tachyon01/Sem)

Comment: These seems like two questions (integration + plot). First, for the integration, can you [edit] your question so your code is a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?  We can't run your code as is. What are example values for `P` or `beta`?

Comment: @SecretAgentMan I have edited the question by adding other parts of my code. The plot is what I will do after the error is resolved. The error comes on step before integration for now, while calculating cdf. Also, I have attached link to full text and my initial code in previous comment.
Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks! Putting the sample values in the question makes it easier for people to help you rather than go to an external site to see your full code.

Comment: For now, I moved to mathematica to evaluate the equation where I was successful. I will now save the results and can import those in matlab for further work.